# Is there a way to generate random numbers in discrete increments using math.random() in lua?

Tags: random, lua, numbers, love2d

I'm trying to test out game mechanics by writing lua code in the LÖVE game development environment. My intent is to have enemy units spawn in one of five lanes and travel across the screen. At the moment, I am able to generate said units and constrain them to the boundaries of where the "lanes" would be. However, I am not sure how to have them spawn explicitly in one of five lanes.

Right now, I am using math.random() to choose a number between the top and bottom boundaries of the lanes. Enemy unit sprites are 32x32, so five discrete lanes will cover a total of 160 pixels of the screen. Right now, I have the boundaries set to 240 and 400 (middle of the screen's height). How do I generate a random number in increments of 32 such that enemies will spawn in one of five possible lanes?

*EDIT: So, it seems that the boundaries are not actually set to the middle. Will be trying to figure out the coordinates on that, but if someone can toss me a freebie tip on that I'd be happy! :D*

My current working code is as follows:

```
-- Axis-based collision detection. Effective for rectangular units; does not work well with circles and non-quad shapes.

function CheckCollision(x1,y1,w1,h1, x2,y2,w2,h2)
  return x1 < x2+w2 and
         x2 < x1+w1 and
         y1 < y2+h2 and
         y2 < y1+h1
end

debug = true


-- Timers declared here to reference later.
createEnemyTimerMax = 0.4
createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax

-- Delcares images; will actually be established in love.load and brought out in love.draw
enemyImg = nil

enemies = {}

function love.load(arg)
    enemyImg = love.graphics.newImage('assets/cat.png')
end


function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown('escape') then
        love.event.push('quit')
    end

    --Generates enemies.
    --Create 5 if/then conditions to account for each lane? 
    --Conditions dependent on createEnemyTimer being < 0 and # of enemies in lane < 5
    --First condition is met; how do we create the second?
    --Will each lane need its own timer?
    createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimer - (.5 * dt)
    if createEnemyTimer < 0 then
        createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax

        -- Create an enemy
        randomNumber = math.random(240,400)
        newEnemy = { y = randomNumber, x = 650, img = enemyImg }
        table.insert(enemies, newEnemy)
    end

    --Updates position of enemies.
    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        enemy.x = enemy.x - (200 * dt)

        if enemy.x < 0 then -- remove enemies when they pass off the screen
            table.remove(enemies, i)
        end
    end

    -- Collision detection.
    -- For MSJ, collision should prevent PC from moving onto enemy's square.

    --[[

    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        for j, bullet in ipairs(bullets) do
            if CheckCollision(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.img:getWidth(), enemy.img:getHeight(), bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.img:getWidth(), bullet.img:getHeight()) then
                table.remove(bullets, j)
                table.remove(enemies, i)
                score = score + 1
            end
        end

        if CheckCollision(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.img:getWidth(), enemy.img:getHeight(), player.x, player.y, player.img:getWidth(), player.img:getHeight())
        and isAlive then
            table.remove(enemies, i)
            isAlive = false
        end
    end

    ]]

end

function love.draw(dt)
    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        love.graphics.draw(enemy.img, enemy.x, enemy.y)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the approach on how to generate the five enemies, each on a lane. What about generating 5 random numbers that mark the relative position of each lane? Then you add this relative position to the beginning of each lane. For instance:

```
local enemies = {}
local origin_y, height = 240, 32
for i=1,5 do
   local relative_y = math.random(32)
   local y = origin_y + height * i  + relative_y
   table.insert(enemies, { x = math.random(), y = y})
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still fairly new to lua, much less coding, so I have a few questions regarding your suggestion, if you wouldn't mind helping me figure them out. This is all a learning process for me!

1)  What is the purpose of establishing several of these variables as local? The other functions that call the enemies table only deals with their movement and images. 

2) In that second line, I understand you are establishing origin_y as the baseline coordinate, but what are you defining with height = 240, 32?

(continued in second comment)

Comment: 3) When you define local y, what is explicitly being calculated? / 4) In the table.insert function at the end of the code, why is x set to math.random()? Is there a specific reason for this? I set it to 650 initially so that enemies were generated offscreen. / 5) Also in the table.insert function, why are you adding { x = math.random(), y = y} to the end of the array? In the original code I posted, table.insert() placed the variable newEnemy into the enemies table, which also established the image file being used for the enemy. Was this simply omitted for your example?

Comment: @KyleRogacion local keyword bounds a variable to a block scope, like `let` in Javascript, or defining variables in strongly-typed languages such as C or Java. Not localising variables makes the variable global (the variables is bound to the global scope (there's a predefined table called _G that contains all the global variables). Regarding 2) Lua allows multiple variable assignment. In that line origin_y is 240 and height is 32. 3) Every lane is 32 height, if the baseline starts at 240, the baselines of all lanes are 240, 272, 304, 336, 369.

Comment: @KyleRogacion OK, I realize I made a mistake there, height should be 40 and the baseline values for all lanes should be 240, 280, 320, 360 and 400. Actually by height I meant a lane's width, so maybe width is better variable name. So y is for each lane a random value between a lane's baseline and max value (relative_y should be a random value between 0 and 40) 5) Right, it was a simplification, I missed your code.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, but I wanted to thank you for your response. I've figured out a way to get what I want working. Your in-depth reply has been very helpful for me to get my bearings.

Comment: @KyleRogacion Sometimes finding the solution for a problem is not a direct answer, but a thinking process. In that regard I glad to hear my response was helpful in some way :)